# Filleting Lines without user selection

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

In my current code that I am running through excel, I am opening an AutoCAD file and adding a variety of lines.  At the moment I have built a list of coordinates, adding them to an array and then having the following command being executed through a loop:

```
Set lineObj = DWGFile.ModelSpace.AddLine(StartPoint, EndPoint)
```

Works great and putting the lines where I need them.  However I am not sure of how to track these lines and refer to them later.

Right now I am looking into filleting and chamfering two lines.  So far the example scripts I have seen have the user select the two things to be filleted/chamfered.  In my case it it might be the first lineObj added (say top line), and the third lineObj added (say right side).  Is there a nice way to do this?

So far I have been manually calculating my chamfer coordinates and simply drawing straight lines between all coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User selection You can eliminate using `SelectionSets`.

```
Dim Name As String
Dim selset As AcadSelectionSet
Set selset = ThisDrawing.SelectionSets.Add(Name)
selset.Select(acSelectionSetAll , p1, ,p2 , fileterType, filterData )
```

Where:

- `Name` has to be unique,
- `acSelectionSetAll` is one of available mode - read more about `AcSelectType`
- `p1, p2` are optional - means points crossing or window - helpfull in declare range of selection
- `fileterType` and `filterData` are also optional and let You limit selection to select entities by type, color, layer and other properties.

Comment: With SelectionSets, does Last or Previous work?  So immediately after adding a line I could create a selection set using last?

Comment: Yes. but Last is good when You create an entity by SendCommand. When You use ModelSpace.AddLine, You have a reference, so You can Use 
Dim ssobjs(0 To 1) As AcadEntity
Set ssobjs(0) = lineObj 
select.AddItems ssobjs

Answer (score 0):

So in my on going research, I stumbled across this AutoDESK article, and some related articles as well.  It sounds like its the property I am looking for but I am not totally sure at the moment.  I am posting the link below as a reference in case others are looking for the same information.

Set lineObj = DWGFile.ModelSpace.AddLine(StartPoint, EndPoint)("Line_Name")

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-5656E0DF-64F4-4117-BA31-64E6C2C55877-htm.html

Comment: Some objects like layers, layouts, blocks and so one has names. it's property the same way as a color for an entity, or a start point for the line, You can easily manipulate this, if an object has such property, but unfortunately, a line has no this property, so You can not use it in the same way. 
I'm working on ZWCAD not AutoCAD so there may be some differences, but I suppose not in this case.

Comment: If a reference to the object is not what You need, and You need to identify Your entities later, You can add XData to the entity.